# Правильный редирект с WWW на без

Tags: .htaccess

Имеется следующий код в **.htaccess** на главной директории web-сайта.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Данном правилом идёт переадресация с **"www.site.com на site.com"**

Но с "www.site.com/category на site.com/category" переадресация не работает, так как в папке "category" имеется ещё один .htaccess для ЧПУ.

Как сделать, чтобы переадресация с **"www на без"** РАБОТАЛ во всех категориях сайта?

Спасибо заранее и всех с **Новым годом**.

Comment: Насколько знаю наследование в глубину идет только если внутри нет файла  .htaccess поэтому думаю что ни как. Но может я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Просто у модулей свои правила, в котором нельзя размещать в корне .htaccess, поэтому внутри приходится создать .htaccess с определенными правилами. Странно, что никак.